# MVVM, Can you bind command in ViewModel to Button in ItemsRepeater when ItemsSource is ObservableCollection<Model> and a property of the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3

I am building a WinUI 3 application that presents a user with a list of `Animal` `ID`s, along with a `Button` beside each `ID` that the user can click to view information about that specific `Animal`. I am using an `ItemsRepeater`, whose `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Animal>` inside an `AnimalViewModel`, so I can create a list of `TextBox` with a `Button` beside it using a `DataTemplate` -- the `TextBox` will have as its value the `Animal.ID`. I also want to use the MVVM design pattern to accomplish this, but this is my first time trying it.

For now, I want the ability to click a `Button` and have it display a dialog box with the `Animal.ID` it corresponds to (the `TextBox` adjacent to it). I have tried implementing this by using an `ICommand` and defining a function to display a `MessageDialog` in my `AnimalViewModel`, then defining the custom `ICommand` in its own file.

The issue seems to be that since I have bound my `ItemsRepeater` to `ObservableCollection<Animal>` in my `AnimalViewModel`, I can't bind the `Button` to the command in my `AnimalViewModel`. This leads me to believe I am not using MVVM correctly or I have improperly structured my code, but I am not sure what to change/how to move forward.

`Error`

```
BindingExpression path error: 'DisplayIDsCommand' property not found on 'MAIT.Models.Animal'
```

Below is the relevant code. I am able to create the list but I cannot get the `Button` to exhibit the desired behavior (please forgive any glaring errors, I had to simplify the code for this question):

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
    <Window
    x:Class="MAIT.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MAIT"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" xmlns:l="using:MAIT.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <muxc:StackLayout x:Name="VerticalStackLayout" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="8"/>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="AnimalTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="text" Text="{Binding ID}"></TextBlock>
                    <Button Command="{Binding DisplayIDsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=text, Path=Text}">View</Button>-
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                MaxHeight="500">
            <muxc:ItemsRepeater
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Animals}"
                Layout="{StaticResource VerticalStackLayout}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AnimalTemplate}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using MAIT.ViewModels;

// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace MAIT
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty window that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            MainGrid.DataContext = new AnimalViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

`Animal.cs`

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MAIT.Models
{
    internal class Animal : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string _ID;
        
        public Animal(string id)
        {
            ID = id;
        }

        public string ID
        { 
            get
            {
                return _ID;
            }
            set
            {
                _ID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ID");
            } 
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

`AnimalViewModel.cs`

```
using MAIT.Commands;
using MAIT.Models;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace MAIT.ViewModels
{
    internal class AnimalViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public IDsCommand DisplayIDsCommand;

        public AnimalViewModel()
        {
            Animals = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
            DisplayIDsCommand = new IDsCommand(DisplayIDs);
            GetAnimals();
        }

        private void GetAnimals()
        {
        

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Animal animal = new Animal(i.ToString());
                Animals.Add(animal);
            }
        }
        
        public async void DisplayIDs(string id)
        {
            MessageDialog t = new MessageDialog(id);
            await t.ShowAsync();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Animal> _Animals;
        public ObservableCollection<Animal> Animals
        {
            get
            {
                return _Animals;
            }
            set
            {
                _Animals = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Animals");
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

`IDsCommand.cs`

```
using MAIT.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MAIT.Commands
{
    internal class IDsCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        private Action<string> _Execute;
        public IDsCommand(Action<string> execute)
        {
            _Execute = execute;
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _Execute.Invoke(parameter as string);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to bind the `Command` property to a source property of a parent element, you need to get a reference to the parent element somehow. In Win UI, you cannot use something `RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsRepeater`.

You could workaround this by creating an attached property that sets the `DataContext` of the `Button` to the parent `ItemsRepeater`:

```
public static class AncestorSource
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AncestorTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AncestorType",
            typeof(Type),
            typeof(AncestorSource),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(Type), OnAncestorTypeChanged)
    );

    public static void SetAncestorType(FrameworkElement element, Type value) =>
        element.SetValue(AncestorTypeProperty, value);

    public static Type GetAncestorType(FrameworkElement element) =>
        (Type)element.GetValue(AncestorTypeProperty);

    private static void OnAncestorTypeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement target = (FrameworkElement)d;
        if (target.IsLoaded)
            SetDataContext(target);
        else
            target.Loaded += OnTargetLoaded;
    }

    private static void OnTargetLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement target = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        target.Loaded -= OnTargetLoaded;
        SetDataContext(target);
    }

    private static void SetDataContext(FrameworkElement target)
    {
        Type ancestorType = GetAncestorType(target);
        if (ancestorType != null)
            target.DataContext = FindParent(target, ancestorType);
    }

    private static object FindParent(DependencyObject dependencyObject, Type ancestorType)
    {
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
        if (parent == null)
            return null;

        if (ancestorType.IsAssignableFrom(parent.GetType()))
            return parent;

        return FindParent(parent, ancestorType);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AnimalTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock x:Name="text" Text="{Binding ID}"></TextBlock>
        <Button local:AncestorSource.AncestorType="muxc:ItemsRepeater"
                Command="{Binding DataContext.DisplayIDsCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=text, Path=Text}">View</Button>-
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2022/01/20/bind-to-a-parent-element-in-winui-3/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

your first WPF appears to be well-on-its-way.

If you want to bind to your command, you will need to use a private field along with the getter and setter, such as with the Animals property, and call OnPropertyChanged in its setter as well. This will let the button know when a command is assigned!

Here are a few friendly pointers if you are interested about learning MVVM:

Consider replacing the using in the local parameter to `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MAIT"`.
In MVVM `DataContext` property can be set in the Window's constructor but usually it's put in the XALM above `<Grid>` as

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:AnimalViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Because this context will not allow you to use local.ViewModels, you can declare another xmlns as `xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MAIT.ViewModels"`

If you are using recent .NET versions, you might appreciate using `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new(propertyName));` as the method body for OnPropertyChanged. Moreover, you can use `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` to automatically get the calling member's name by changing the OnPropertyChanged's signature to `private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")`.